# get servername with sqlserver name in computer local or network

Tags: c#, winforms

```
DataTable table = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources();
foreach (DataRow server in table.Rows)
{
    cmbshowallsqlserver.Items.Add(server[table.Columns["ServerName"]].ToString());
}
```

This code give me only name of computer. I want give me computername with sqlserver name.
for example this code give me anfd-pc but I need for example anfd-pc\sqlexpress or anfd-pc\zarnegar

Comment: What other values are available in `table`?

Comment: name of computer name for example David-pc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ServerName` column in the table you're getting from `GetDataSources()` has exactly that, the server name.  You can also get the *instance* name from the `InstanceName` column.  [See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator.getdatasources.aspx) for other available options.

So your code would become something like this:

```
cmbshowallsqlserver.Items.Add(
    string.Format(@"{0}\{1}",
                  server[table.Columns["ServerName"]],
                  server[table.Columns["InstanceName"]])
);
```

Comment: this code is correctly but nothing InstanceName found in computer ? I have 2 sqlserver express and other name.

Answer (score 1):

```
DataTable table = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources();

foreach (DataRow server in table.Rows)
{
    string servername = server[table.Columns["ServerName"]].ToString();

    // you can get that using the instanceName property 
    string instancename = server[table.Columns["InstanceName"].ToString();

    //and version property tells you the version of sql server i.e 2000, 2005, 2008 r2 etc
    string sqlversion = server[table.Columns["Version"].ToString();

    //to form the servername you can combine the server and instancenames as
    string sqlserverfullname = String.Format("{0}\{1}",servername, instancename);

    cmbshowallsqlserver.Items.Add(sqlserverfullname);
}
```

Comment: Perfect G. Is there a way to get the datasource name the same way for the connection string